# expected value of number of comparison in binary search tree

Tags: probability

Im trying to learn how average case analysis for a binary search tree works. It is said that to find the average number of comparisons, one must find the sum of the probability of searching for k(sub i) times the number of comparisons to find k(sub i).

This is supposed to be the formula for expected value.

But I thought expected number of comparisons had to use the probability of the number of comparisons to find k(sub i), NOT the the probability of searching for k(sub i).

Would both methods get the same answer?

Comment: The title is confusing -- why are you taking an average and then an expected value? Don't you mean just one of them?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)  To find the mean of $Y$, where $Y=f(X)$, we don't need to find the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @joriki thanks for clearing it up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a node in a full binary tree: expected number of comparisons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237223/finding-a-node-in-a-full-binary-tree-expected-number-of-comparisons)